# How to avoid Segmentation Fault in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

This my code. I am trying tp take string input and turn it into lowercase. However, it always appear Segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c1,c2;
    c1 = getchar();
    c2 = tolower(c1);
    int length = strlen(c1);
    printf("%d is the length. %d is lowercase of %d", length, c2, c1);
    return 0;
}
```

It shows

```
Segmentation Fault
```

What's wrong with my code

Comment: There's no way that code compiles.

Comment: could you explain for me please. I am just beginning to study C it so confusing

Comment: For starters, your code won't compile as you have it shown.  `strlen(c1)` is an attempt to pass a char into a function that expects `char*` (pointer to char).  So I suspect you are getting a compiler error and then attempting to run an earlier build of your program that had a significant issue.

Comment: Your compiler should show some warnings like "Implicitely declaring function `tolower`. And something like "imcompatible argument type for `strlen`. Expecting char* while argument is of type char" and so on...

Comment: @selbie with ANSI settings it could compile. The linker won't check argument types and when that function is called with wrong types, that is where the s**t hits the fan. ;)

Comment: You should increase diagnostig level. For GCC or Clang use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic". Then read and address every warning. Only afterwards you should try to run it.

Comment: You should use type `int` for individual characters.  Use `char` when they're in an array (i.e., strings).  That way you can detect `EOF` etc. when dealing with individual characters.  And don't try to pass an individual character to `strlen`.  That can't possibly work, and in any case, you already *know* it's a single character.  If you instead want to operate on strings rather than characters, you'll need to use a `char` array rather than a single value.

Comment: @Gerhardh - ANSI C had stronger type checking than that, didn't it?  K&R C would have likely accepted it.  But we're talking 30+ year old standards. I tried his code with `std=c89` and `-ansi` and it still balked on the strlen call being passed a non-pointer type.

Comment: @selbie As long as a function prototype was available for `strlen`, it should have given an error.  But OP didn't seem to include `<string.h>`, so perhaps it was undeclared.  There may have been a compiler warning about that,

Answer (score 0):

When you define c1 and c2 you define them as a single character, define them as pointers *c1 or string c1[100].

In addition you have to import the libraries for the use of strlen and tolower which are string.h and ctype.h respectively.